# How to perform topic modeling on Japanese corpus data

Tags: python, topic-modeling

I have been applying topic modeling to English corpus until now. I want to understand how can I do something similar to Japanese corpus where input is a dataframe that contains text in Japanese language and output is key words that relate to topics. I want to use LDA algorithm. Before that I would like to do TF IDF to convert word to vectors.

Comment: It seems like you already have the answers to your own question.

Comment: I would like to understand if it can be applied to Japanese corpus. One blocker which i can think of is the stop words removal. Not sure how can i find any Japanese stop words. Can you help with any links or code examples?